# show Finder file properties

Tags: macos, finder

Via

```
ws = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
ws.selectFile_inFileViewerRootedAtPath_(filename, None)
```

I can open a new Finder window and select the specific file.

Now I not just want to select a file but also open the Finder properties window for that file.

Is there an easy way to do that? (Preferable Python code, but I can translate myself.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any Cocoa API that does this directly.  However, the following AppleScript does the job:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    open information window of item 1 of (selection as list)
end tell
```

You can invoke this using `NSAppleScript` or the `osascript` command. From Cocoa, you could also use the Scripting Bridge, but I'm not sure that helps for Python. (A bit of searching of Apple's docs finds a recommendation of [`py-appscript`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/appscript/) for using the Scripting Bridge from Python.)